# "pdfLatex has stopped working" Prompt when being called from Matlab

Tags: matlab, report, latex, tex, pdflatex

I am tring to call pdflatex in matlab. The code is below

```
clc;
% analysis
i = 10;
n = 'Ashwani Roy';
x = 1:0.5:100;
y = sin(x.^2);
plot(x,y);
saveas(gcf, 'output', 'png')
%% write to tex
fid = fopen('Report.tex','w');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n','\documentclass{article}');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n','\usepackage{graphicx}');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n','\begin{document}');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n',strcat(num2str(i),':',n));
fprintf(fid,'%s\n','Some other text blah blah ');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n','\includegraphics{output.png}');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n','\end{document}');
fclose(fid);
%% DOS Invoke 
[status,cmdout] =dos('"C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/...
                       miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe" -shell-escape ...
                      --src -interaction=nonstopmode Report.tex');
```

It works from and creates a Report.pdf which has the data i wanted but it throws windows error prompt saying ***psdlatex.exe has stopped working. Please close or debug the program.***

I am wondering how to suppress this prompt or fix the root cause of this.

Comment: for me it works without any error. Try `dos` without output arguments and alternatively try `system`. Also update your Miktex distribution. Have you tried to simply output text without a picture? Do you get the same error if you invoke the command directly in the cmd console?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Tried both , no difference .

Comment: once you got the .tex file, have you tried compiling it with another Gui, like texworks packed in Miktex?

Comment: look at the command you are calling. breaking a string into different lines may not work. i'm not with Matlab now so i'm not sure, but you should concatenate multiple lines of string, rather than simply add ... before new line.

Comment: @Yvon it complies in miktex 2.9. I know i can contacatenate and build a big string. this is just for demo . In reality these text will be read from read from database and I will repalce some bits based on my analysis and stuff the graphs etc and produce pdf.

Comment: The question is more worthy than the answer! Thanks for that question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the fix. I just reinstalled the entire MikTex 2.9 and it fixed the issue. Not sure what was causing the thread to die before but could be incomplete install.